# Memory consumption by Atom text editor

Tags: memory, sublimetext3, atom-editor, text-editor

Why Atom uses more memory and takes more time to start as compare to sublime text editor ?

Answer (score 2):

From Atom's [FAQ](https://discuss.atom.io/c/faq) (Hint: Try searching before asking):

[Atom isn't designed to be a tiny native-code editor. If the ultimate in speed is what you're after, Atom probably isn't what you're looking for at least for now ... and possibly not ever depending on what you're expecting](https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-feels-slow-or-is-consuming-too-much-cpu-or-memory/32662).

1. Atom is an Electron application.
2. Electron uses Chromium source as base.
3. Chrome/Chromium are known to be memory hogs.

Why then would anyone use it?
Well, the [homepage](https://aton.io) states it on its **headline**:

A hackable text editor
for the 21st Century

Some of us like the idea of hacking every aspect of our work environment using common tools as javascript or CSS.